# Do two AWS accounts created in the same region share the same VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Do two AWS accounts created in the same region share the same VPC, Because the VPC is in the level of region? Or each account in the same region has its own VPC?

Example:
What about if user_A with account_A create an EC2 instance in region Ohio and another user_B with account_B create another EC2 instance in the same region Ohio, Do these two different instances are in the same VPC? Because as I know (if I am not wrong) a region is attached with a single VPC..?

Comment: No. A VPC is a thing you create and configure in your account, and you can have up to 100 per-account per-region: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/amazon-vpc-limits.html . It would be a huge security breach if all accounts shared the same VPC - it is meant to improve security, similar to a firewall.

Comment: I've noticed that almost all your questions got answered yet not a single answer was accepted. Accepting useful answers is not only a good practice, but reduces duplicates and increases chances of your questions being actually answered.

Comment: VPC stands for Virtual Private Cloud. If it was shared, it wouldn't be Private.

Answer (score 5):

A VPC is a logically isolated network. And a single aws account can have many VPC's. This then will naturally mean two VPC's in two different accounts are also separate. Network traffic between them will need to be configured unless you opt to setup sharing.

Shared VPC's can be configured if you wished at a Organization level - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/vpc-sharing-a-new-approach-to-multiple-accounts-and-vpc-management/

Comment: What about if user_A with account_A create an EC2 instance in region Ohio and another user_B with account_B create another EC2 instance in the same region Ohio, Do these two different instances are in the same VPC? Because as I know (if I am not wrong) a region is attached with a single VPC..?

Comment: You don't attach a region to a VPC, you deploy a VPC to a region, and then configure subnets within the VPC. As mentioned, typically VPC's are logically isolated networks. Anything within them is in an isolated network. So in your example, no, typically not, unless you wanted it to be that way and thus configured it. If your asking if peoples 'applications' and 'servers' run in the same VPC when they do not have a relationship, definitely not. They may? run side by side on physical hardware (if availability zone the same) but are always logically separated.

Comment: I suggest reading this AWS Whitepaper on logical separation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/logical-separation/logical-separation.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion...

It could not be in the same VPC, but you can use VPC Peering to interact these resources privately. You can setup easily VPC Peering between accounts. Also, You cannot use same CIDR block between these VPC's.

[image: VPC Peering Schema]

Answer (score 0):

No. VPC is exclusive and managed per customer account.

[image]

Additionally:

- A VPC exist and tied to one region
- You can create subnet(public and/or private) under VPC.
- Each subnet must reside entirely within one Availability Zone and cannot span zones.
- A region contains at least 2 availability zone (data center).